# Alfresco - How to log all custom properties in audit

Tags: alfresco

I have created custom type in alfresco and added some properties to it.
Now whenever anyone access file having this custom type, I want to audit all properties of custom type, but alfresco only auditing modified/added/deleted properties.

How to log all properties of custom type in audit?

Thanks, Yogesh

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read the [documentation on the Audit Service](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/serv-audit-about.html) and then if you get stuck, ask a more specific question including what you've tried and what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The alfresco audit service has extractors and generators.
Generators can audit information that is not present in the input path.

I think that you should be able to use a generator to audit all your custom properties.